# TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm following this https://jestjs.io/docs/en/bypassing-module-mocks which consists basically of a createUser.js and a jest for it. In my case I'm using TypeScript

```
// createUser.ts
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export const createUser = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('http://website.com/users', {method: 'POST'});
  const userId = await response.text();
  return userId;
};
```

```
// jest for createUser.ts
jest.mock('node-fetch');

import fetch from 'node-fetch';
const {Response} = jest.requireActual('node-fetch');

import {createUser} from './createUser';

test('createUser calls fetch with the right args and returns the user id', async () => {
  fetch.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(new Response('4')));

  const userId = await createUser();

  expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://website.com/users', {
    method: 'POST',
  });
  expect(userId).toBe('4');
});
```

Although, instead of getting `TypeError: response.text is not a function` as the tutorial describes, I receive `TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported`.

When I change to `fetch.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve('http://website.com/users')` the `TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported` is gone and I get `TypeError: response.text is not a function`.

So, how to actually mock the response in the jest?